# Request.Form ASP not Working

Tags: asp-classic, request.form

This feels like a very stupid question, but I've been trying and searching for hours and can't figure out the problem. I'm new to pretty much all web development, and this was a test to figure out how to access form data on a new page. It just will not work for me. I have contactus.html and contactusaction.asp saved in the same folder on my desktop. Clicking submit loads contactusaction.asp, but "fname" will not appear on the next page no matter what I try. I've even copy and pasted other people's request.form examples, and I still have yet to get the comand to work in any way.

contactus.html:

```
<html>
<head>
Hello
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="contactusaction.asp"/>


<input type="text" name="fname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

contactusaction.asp:

```
<html>
<head>Hello:</head>
<body>
<%

Dim x
x=Request.Form("fname")
Response.Write(x)

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're new to web development, then why of all languages are you learning classic ASP?

Comment: Are you sure ASP is set up correctly?

Comment: I'm only trying to use it for a single project I'm working on at work that has users input data into our website and displays data based on their inputs (it's a disease risk calculator). Request.Form seemed like the easiest way to pass the data from one page to the next. If there's a better way, I'd be happy to do something else. I just want to get it working. This is probably the only time I will ever do any web development.

Comment: From your code it looks like you might be closing the `<form>` tag too early. Change `<form method="post" action="contactusaction.asp"/>` to `<form method="post" action="contactusaction.asp">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly question, but after reading "saved in the same folder on my desktop" I have to ask - are you testing this using IIS or some other web server software on your desktop?

If you're just opening the local HTML page directly (double-clicking on the file vs running a local IIS and going to `http://localhost/` or however you have it set up), there's no server running the actual ASP/VBScript code.

Also, reguardless of the answer to the above question, you should definitely fix the `<form>` tag as Guido Gautier mentions in his comment to your question.

This:

```
<form method="post" action="contactusaction.asp"/>
```

Should be this:

```
<form method="post" action="contactusaction.asp">
```